# Using a list with two tuples as a parameter for a function: python

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

(I am a beginner so bear with me if this is a dumb question)

Problem to solve from class:

Following the function design recipe, define a function distance great circle that
takes in two parameters: a list points and a float R. The float R is a nonnegative radius
of the sphere. The list points has exactly two items in it. Each item is a tuple (latitude,
longitude), in radians, of a point on the surface of a sphere. The function returns the greatcircle distance between the two points whose latitude-longitude coordinates are stored in
points. Include two examples in your docstring.

This is what I have:

```
 def distance_great_circle(points:list, R: float):
    """
    Description: Takes in a list 'points' (2 latitudes, 2 longitudes) and the float 'R' (nonnegative radius of the sphere), returning the great circle distance.
    
    >>> distance_great_circle([(34, 59),(67, 42)], 20)
    
    
    >>> distance_great_circle([(152, 109),(82, 66)], 40)
    
    
    """
    import math
    R >= 0
    points = [(lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)]
    
    return R * (math.acos(math.sin(lat1) * math.sin(lat2) + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.cos(lon1 - lon2)))
```

The code runs into an error as lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 are all undefined. I understand that they are undefined, but I am not quite sure how to define them while following all of these rules in the question. Is there another way I should be doing this?

I think that this means I need to use something different in the tuples and call the latitudes and longitudes into the function by indexing, but I am not quite sure how to format that.

If anything is wrong with the code other than the lat/lon variables thats okay I will figure that out after fixing this, I just need help on how to get my function to take the tuples as arguments for the function.

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: `points` is *already a list of two tuples*. You seem to want to *unpack that iterable into those variables*, in which case, you want, `(lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2) = points`

Comment: You need to unpack the given list, so instead of doing `points = [(lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)]` it should be `[(lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)] = points`. That way the values in the list will get stored in the respective variables, and you will be able to calculate the required value.

Comment: Thank you IronVenom that actually helped sooo much I knew it had to have been a simple fix, thank you!!